# Azure SMS message is not receiving by Hawaii phone numbers

Tags: azure, azure-communication-services

I am started working on Azure SMS service integration. Here, I am able to send an SMS to all the states except Hawaii. Is there any configuration I have to do in the Azure portal or something is missing?

Comment: Circling back, this issue should be fixed now - let us know if you are still having trouble. Thank you for your feedback!